# Downgrade Python without change behavior of base environment

Tags: anaconda, mamba

I'm trying to switch over to using Mamba for my Python installation (Windows 10). Previously, I've just been installing Python using the installer from `python.org` and `pip`.

However, I have some one-off scripts I'd like to be able to run in a default environment without having to use `source activate $env` every time. The newest version of Mamba uses Python 3.10, but most of these scripts were written for Python 3.9.7. I'd like to downgrade the Python installation in the default environment to 3.9.7. I've tried doing this using `mamba install python=3.9.7`, which initially seems to work.

However, I get the following problem. When I run Python 3.10 using `python` in a command prompt after installing Mamba (i.e., before running the previous command to downgrade to 3.9.7), the interpreter launches and works correctly. Any packages I add to the base environment become available.

But after I downgrade the base environment to Python 3.9.7, I get the following warning when running `python`:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

The interpreter does launch, but packages added to the base environment indeed fail to load when I attempt to import them.

I can get around this by running `mamba activate base` (though for some reason I don't understand, this is only successful from cmd and not PowerShell, which is annoying, since that's the shell I use by default). After this, `python` launches the interpreter without any warnings, and packages added to the base environment load as expected.

But what I'd like to do is downgrade Python to 3.9.7 and make it work like the default 3.10 environment, where the base environment is available without needing to manually activate it every time, since this is what I want for my one-off scripts that I want to be able to just run by clicking on them.

Is there a way I can downgrade the version of Python in Mamba's base environment, but make it work like the prepackaged version (i.e., without needing to issue `mamba activate base` every time)? Is the way to do this just to use an older version of Mamba that comes with Python 3.9.7?

Comment: In case this does turn out to be the right answer, I've found that the Mamba installer that comes with Python 3.9.10 (which should also be fine for me) is Mambaforge 4.11.0-4.

Comment: Using Mambaforge 4.11.0-4 did solve my problem, but I'll leave this question up since I'm still curious about whether it's possible to do this via a downgrade from a newer Mamba version (since finding the right old version was not entirely straightforward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*Is there a way I can downgrade the version of Python in Mamba's base environment...?*"

Yes, but you shouldn't. It's best to leave **base** alone - it should strictly be used for Conda/Mamba infrastructure, not for running user scripts. If you want a default Python 3.9.7 environment, then create one, disable `auto_activate_base`, and have that new environment activate when your shell starts up.

Comment: I've found that I can disable `auto_activate_base` using `mamba config --set auto_activate_base false`, but I'm not sure how to get another environment to start up with the shell. I'd know how to do it in a bash-style shell, but I'm not sure how to activate it by default in cmd/pwsh.

Edit: Found something here that seems like it ought to work: https://superuser.com/questions/1090141/does-powershell-have-any-sort-of-bashrc-equivalent

Comment: And here's the solution for cmd: https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-equivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux

Comment: @Jigsaw thanks for documenting those! I'm not a Windows user, so it's good to know where I can recommend how things work with PowerShell and cmd.exe.

Comment: I will also note (for anyone else who may try this) that you should NOT set up the cmd autorun file before installing mamba/conda. If you do that, the cmd processes the installer spawns all fail since the startup environment command can't be found, and it spawns more and more subprocesses to retry until it locks/crashes the computer. That was fun!